# Branching off a different branch from PR

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase, pull-request

So I have a branch called `feature 1` as part of a pull request to merge into `dev`, where I've done some work.

There's another branch called `feature 2` that's part of a different pull request where the page I'm working on was refactored.

What's the best way to get `feature 2` into the `feature 1` branch? Should I be branching off `feature 2`, merging `feature 2` into the `feature 1` branch, or rebasing `feature 1` onto `feature 2`?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your branch situation looks something like this:

```
      A---B feature2
     /     
o---o---o dev
         \
          C---D---E feature1
```

What you want is to *rebase* your work in `feature1` on top of `feature2`:

```
      A---B feature2
     /
o---o---o dev
         \
          A'---B'---C'---D'---E' feature1
```

To do that, you can run:

```sh
git rebase feature2 feature1
```

Which basically says "*checkout `feature1` and rebase it on top of `feature2`*". Of course, be prepared to resolve the conflict that will inevitably appear in the page that both you and the author of `feature2` modified.

#### Background

You may wonder why rebase? Well, because it produces a clear history regardless of which branch gets merged first into `dev`.

For example, let's consider the scenario where `feature2` is merged before `feature1`:

```
      A---B feature2
     /     \
o---o---o---o dev
         \
          A'---B'---C'---D'---E' feature1
```

In that case, once you rebase `feature1` on top of `dev`, Git will detect that the changes introduced by commits `A` and `B` are already in `dev`, so it will remove them from `feature1`:

```
      A---B feature2
     /     \
o---o---o---o dev
             \
              C'---D'---E' feature1
```

What about if `feature1` is rebased before `feature2`:

```
      A---B feature2
     /
o---o---o-----------------------o dev
         \                     /
          A'---B'---C'---D'---E' feature1
```

The same thing applies here. Once you rebase `feature2` on top of `dev`, `A` and `B` are going to be removed from `feature1` because their changes are already present in `dev`:

```
o---o---o---------------------o dev, feature2
         \                   /
          A'---B'---C---D---E feature1
```

Of course, if new commits were added in `feature2` after you rebased your `feature1` on top of it, those commits will still be kept:

```
                                F---G---H feature2
                               /
o---o---o---------------------o dev
         \                   /
          A'---B'---C---D---E feature1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pull requests are not a part of the git protocol. Pull requests are only something implemented by git hosting services such as GitHub to provide a review function before a merge. If your questions is actually related to any feature related to pull requests then you also have to tell us what hosting service you are using. However, in my understanding, your question can be boiled down to what the difference between merge and rebase is, and both those features are a part of the git protocol.

The current state of a branch can be thought of the sum of all commits previous to the commit that branch points to. And as with mathematical sums, the end result does not depend on the order you sum items in, and that is one way to think of the  only difference (kind of) between merges and rebases. So, if you only care about the end result of the current version of the branch, then stop reading and do whatever you think is easiest.

The difference between a rebase and a pull request is how the history will look. A rebase of `feature-1` to `feature-2` simple creates a new branch from `feature-2` and copy all commits on `feature-1` to the new branch, then deletes the `feature-1` branch and rename the new branch `feature-1`. So it is no longer the same commits. They are identical, but they are no longer the same and they have different hashes. In general, this creates a cleaner history, but it is in one way a *less true* history as it looks as if the branch `feature-1` was always created of `feature-2` which it wasn't.

A merge from `feature-2` to `feature-1` will create the same end result of the current version of `feature-1` branch, but the history will show that branch `feature-1` was first created from `main`/`master`, had commits made to it, and then `feature-2` was merged into it before both `feature-1` and `feature-2` were merged back into the default branch.

So, the end result will be the same, it is just a matter of what story you want the repository history to tell. And to many people that rarely matters.